# What's the most pragmatic way to keep track of how far down the page a user has scrolled?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a website right now, where a bunch of animations and graphical events are triggered on scroll(you know the fancy ones). I'm trying to decide how to measure how far down the page the scroll has gotten.

Option one, measure in pixel and trigger events:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
  var scrolllength  = $(window).scrollTop()

switch(key) {
  case 84:
    foo();
    break;
  case 185:
    bar();
    break;
  default:
    return;
}
```

Pros: probably faster

Cons: If the height of anything changes I have to measure and update it manually. This is a static sit, but I do expect a lot of tweaking and tinkering.

Option two, Keeping track of the DOM-elements.

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
  //this will be a bunch of differnt ones but for example
  if(isScrolledIntoView('#div'){
    $('body').css('background','black');
  }
}

function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
```

Pros: dynamic and sort of content agnostic

Cons: as it triggers every time the scroll is triggered, I fear that this approach will risk to make scrolling non smooth. I'll have atleast 20 things of this nature to check for. The page will be divided into different segments o maybe I could start of by checking what segment is visible and then do another check for the items in that specific segment.

I am of course open to more alternatives!

Comment: You could just store the `offset`s for whichever DIVs you need once at the start of the script, like this: `var triggerone = $("#whateverdiv").offset().top`

Comment: That's a really good idea! If you write an answer i'll vote for it. ^^

Comment: Whatever you do, it might be a good idea to rate limit the number of times you respond to the scroll event by using http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

Comment: I havent tried this ever in my life,but here are my 2 cents...
Place some hidden division after every (letssay) 400px and onfocus of that divson,we can ascertain the amount of scrolling that have been done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to store the offsets for whichever DIVs you need once at the start of the script:

```
var triggerone = $("#whateverdiv").offset().top;
var triggertwo = $("#whateverotherdiv").offset().top;

$(document).scroll(function(){
    var scrolllength = $(window).scrollTop()

    switch(scrolllength) {
        case triggerone:
            foo();
            break;
        case triggertwo:
            bar();
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }
}
```

This combines the ease of maintenance of the second solution with the (approximate) speed of the first.

Comment: Please also explain *why* this helps/works. What part of the problem your code solves (as the question was relatively open). Specifically, it tries to mitigate the performance problem I guess, and extends the second solution in the question.

Comment: @Kissaki Point taken, I'll add a reason to the answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Nice answers. Learning stuff.

I made a little fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/vP9TW/2/)

The problem with the `switch`statement is that it checks for equalities and a user usually keeps scrolling. And anyway, I couldn't get it to work with a switch so I used inequalities instead.

Comment: This is not an answer tough … Please post commends as comments (if you can)